# Switching content of numerous elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a main div at top of page with h1, p, and link in this section. Then below i have numerous other divs with different content in them h3, p, a.

Also contained within these divs is a separate link. On click of this link i'd like the content to switch with the content in the main section. e.g.

If you look at this JSFiddle i've created: https://jsfiddle.net/ow1nLh0a/3/

I can only seem to switch the content like below within the jQuery - but this is no use.

```
$(".this-changes").click(function () {
    $(".main-area h1").fadeOut(function () {
        $(".main-area h1").text(($(".main-area h1").text() == 'Title Goes here') ? 'Different Title' : 'Title Goes here').fadeIn();
    })
})
```

If you was to press the 'Change Link' text in 1 of the smaller divs. Then the h1 above would replace with the h3 from the panel where link's been clicked same goes with p and same goes with button link. I can do this for 1 panel no problem, but once it starts getting into multiples it becomes more difficult. I've only created 3 smaller panels on the example (there will be many on the live version).

Thanks

Comment: What you want to do is pass a handle to the link that has been clicked and then look for the sibling h3, you can then use its html to replace the h1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood your request, but here's what I thought you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".this-changes").click(function () {
            $panel = $(this).parents('.panel');
        $(".main-area > h1").fadeOut(function () {       
            $(this).html($panel.find('h3').html()).fadeIn();
        });
        $(".main-area > p").fadeOut(function () {       
            $(this).html($panel.find('p').html()).fadeIn();
        });
        $(".main-area > a").fadeOut(function () {       
            $(this).replaceWith($panel.find('a.button').clone()).fadeIn();
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pass a handle to the link that has been clicked and then look for the sibling h3, you can then use its html to replace the h1.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".this-changes").click(function (event) {
        h3 = $(event.target).siblings('h3')
        $(".main-area h1").fadeOut(function () {
            $(".main-area h1").text(h3.html()).fadeIn();
        })
    })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ow1nLh0a/5/

Comment: Just to take it one step further, https://jsfiddle.net/ow1nLh0a/6/ that is how you would go about doing the other elements.

Comment: That's pretty much perfect cheers :-) Just one thing. I've updated this: https://jsfiddle.net/ow1nLh0a/8/ Can the sub-button link also pass across to the button link in the main area?